# Multiple input value React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im trying to make calculator for norms in React Native. I have problem with taking value of all input once. When I press on button I need to press multiple times to take value of all inputs and get good result.
And my second problem is how to require all inputs were fill or just checking and display error when input is empty.

```
export default function App() {

 // State
 let [quantity, setQuantity] = useState();
 let [percent, setPercent] = useState();
 let [norm, setNorm] = useState();
 let [result, setResult] = useState();
 let [message, setMessage] = useState();
 let [hour, setHour] = useState();
 let [min, setMin] = useState();

 //Function
 const calculate = () =>{
   setResult(Math.floor(quantity * 60 / ( (percent / 100) * norm)));
   if(result > 60){
     setHour(Math.floor(result / 60));
     setMin(Math.floor(result -  hour * 60));
     if(min > 0){setMessage(`${hour}h and ${min}min.`);}
     else{{setMessage(`${hour}h.`);}}
   }
   else{
      setMessage(`${result}min`);
   }   
 }

 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
       <View>
         <Text>Enter quantity:</Text>   
         <TextInput 
           keyboardType='numeric'
           style={styles.input}          
           onChangeText={ (val) => setQuantity(val)}
         />

         <Text>Enter percent: </Text>   
         <TextInput 
           keyboardType='numeric'
           style={styles.input}       
           onChangeText={ (val) => setPercent(val)}
         />

         <Text>Enter norm:</Text>   
         <TextInput 
           keyboardType='numeric'
           style={styles.input} 
           onChangeText={ (val) => setNorm(val)}
         />
       <View>
         <Button  title='Calculate' onPress={calculate}/>
       </View>
         <Text>{message}</Text>
       </View>
     </View>
 );
}`
```